# Replacing Value in Next Row with Output from Function Before Applying Function to Next Row

Tags: r, function

I'm looking at trying to apply a function in R to each row, while updating each row with the output of the function from the previous row. I know that's a mouthful, but here's an example. Let's say I had dataframe, df:

```
df<- data.frame(a=c(10,15,20,25,30), b=c(2,4,5,7,10))
```

And I had a function, funR, that just took the difference between column a and column b:

```
funR<- function(argA, argB){
  c<- argA-argB
  return(c)
}
```

Now a simplified version of what I'd be going for is let's say I apply the function to the first row and get 10 - 2 = 8. I would then want to replace the second row of column a with this output before applying the function to that row, so instead of 15 - 4 I'd be doing 8 - 4. I would then replace 20 in row 3 with 4, and so on and so on.

Edit to show expected output:

```
   a  b
1 10  2 
2  8  4   
3  4  5    
4 -1  7   
5 -8 10
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to include your expected output for the sample data you give.

Comment: last one should be -8 not -6

Comment: Lol, fixed. Stupid of me

Comment: You can implement this recursion relation in a single-line `for` loop. Please take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a one-liner in base R:

### Method 1:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)) df$a[i + 1] <- df$a[i] - df$b[i];
df;
#   a  b
#1 10  2
#2  8  4
#3  4  5
#4 -1  7
#5 -8 10
```

Here we implement the recursion relation `a[i+1] = a[i] - b[i]` in a simple `for` loop. The `for` loop will be very fast, as we directly overwrite existing entries in `df`.

### Method 2

Or alternatively:

```
df$a <- df$a[1] - cumsum(c(0, df$b))[1:length(df$a)];
df;
#   a  b
#1 10  2
#2  8  4
#3  4  5
#4 -1  7
#5 -8 10
```

This is based on the expanded recursion relation, where you can see that e.g. `a[4] = a[1] - (b[1] + b[2] + b[3])`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a faster version if you want to maintain the use of the function `funR`.

```
df<- data.frame(a=c(10,15,20,25,30), b=c(2,4,5,7,10))



funR<- function(argA, argB){
  n = length(argA)
  argC = c(argA[1], argB)
  accumdiff <- function(x){
    Reduce(function(x1,x2) x1-x2, x, accumulate=TRUE)}
  argC = c(argA[1],accumdiff(argC)[c(-1)])
  rev(rev(argC)[-1])
}

df$a <- funR(df$a, df$b)

df

#     a  b
# 1 10  2
# 2  8  4
# 3  4  5
# 4 -1  7
# 5 -8 10
```

Comment: This does not reproduce OPs expected output.

Comment: I got inspired from your post

Comment: This is definitely *not* a "faster version" than the two methods I gave earlier. You can confirm that with a `microbenchmark`.

Comment: Ah, I missed your second solution, @MauritsEvers. That definitely is the fastest with the provided data. Mine suffered from those subsettings, reduction, and revs.

Comment: The `for` loop will be very fast here as well; there’s no dynamic memory allocation, and it simply overwrites entries in `df`. You can test that in benchmark. `for` loops are not always bad in R.

Comment: I agree. I was thinking along that line earlier, but opted for `Reduce` instead.

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this with `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(a = accumulate(b[-n()], `-`, .init = a[1]))
#   a  b
#1 10  2
#2  8  4
#3  4  5
#4 -1  7
#5 -8 10
```

Comment: Wow! This is very clever! But why is `mutate` + `accumulate` slower than my hackish code?

Comment: @hpesoj626  I haven't checked the timings on a bigger data.  May be, the `Reduce` have less checks